# Simulate Actual Keypress For a Certain Amount of Time

Tags: c#, keypress

I have a background timer which records the time when a key is pressed and a separate timer which records the duration. For example: I pressed a key 5 seconds after the timer started and held it for 50ms. Its then stored in a List formatted as ("5000//50").

I have figured out everything, except how to press the key for the recorded duration. The playback is also supposed to simulate a actual keypress so a game would detect it. All other solutions here on stackoverflow sadly don't work properly in my case..

The only code which comes close, is the one bellow, but it doesn't work properly nor do games detect it;

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

const int KEY_DOWN_EVENT = 0x0001; //Key down flag
const int KEY_UP_EVENT = 0x0002; //Key up flag

public static void HoldKey(byte key, int duration, int pause)
{
    long totalDuration = 0;
    while (totalDuration < duration)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(pause);
        keybd_event(key, 0, KEY_DOWN_EVENT, 0);
        keybd_event(key, 0, KEY_UP_EVENT, 0);
        totalDuration += pause;
    }
}
```

I called this function using:

```
//example for items in timeLine (List<string>) are "5000//50", "6000//40", "7000//60"
int previousTime = 0;
foreach (string item in timeLine)
{
    var split = Regex.Split(item, "//");
    int pause = Int32.Parse(split[0]) - previousTime;

    SendKeys.HoldKey((byte)Keys.W, Int32.Parse(split[1]), pause);

    previousTime = item[0] + item[1];
}
```

I'm not a programming expert, so I'm sure there are better ways to achieve a working method.. I don't even know if its possible, but I'll be happy for every help I can get :)